# Calculating area with DotSpatial from GPS

Tags: gps, dotspatial

I have a problem when taking the information from the GPS of my car. I want to calculate the worked area according to the latitude and longitude provided by the equipment. So far I am using .Net core 5 and DotSpatial. I cannot find the area of ​​the polygon.

flow: extract the data from the GPS API (lat, lon, alt), I convert it to separate arrays and then I give the step to DotSpatial

I am in Chile zone UTM 19S.

proj4_ed50 and proj4_rdnew have been a headache because of my ignorance.

example

x = -352073233333

y = -718182916667

I just need an orientation to achieve my purpose.

```
internal static void prueba2(double[] x, double[] y, double[] z)
        {
     
            double[] xy = new double[2 * x.Length];
            int ixy = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= x.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                xy[ixy] = x[i];
                xy[ixy + 1] = y[i];
                z[i] = 0;
                ixy += 2;
            }

            string proj4_ed50 = "+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";
            string proj4_rdnew = "+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs";

            DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo src =
                DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo.FromProj4String(proj4_ed50);
            DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo trg =
                DotSpatial.Projections.ProjectionInfo.FromProj4String(proj4_rdnew);

            var zw = new double[xy.Count() / 2];
            var pointsArray = xy.ToArray();

            Reproject.ReprojectPoints(pointsArray, zw, src, trg, 0, pointsArray.Length / 2);

            var points = new List<DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate>(pointsArray.Length / 2);
            for (int i = 0; i < pointsArray.Length / 2; i++)
                points.Add(new DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate(pointsArray[i * 2], pointsArray[i * 2 + 1]));

            var poly = new DotSpatial.Topology.Polygon(points);
            
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the code, nor why *proj4_ed50* and *proj4_rdnew* are the same (and both WGS84 / UTM 19 S projection's) string, if you are trying to reproject between them. But if you have already the X and Y coordinates of successive points you can compute the cartesian enclosed area with the [Schoelase formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) (Gauss area formula), also in real time, from any initial point, without the need of construct a polygon object.